# List operations in Python

Tags: python

I have two arrays

```
x=[1,2,3]
y=[1,-2,3]
```

I want to compute the scalar product (x|y) and the norm l1 of y

I don't understand why the following code works :

```
y_norm=sum([abs(u) for u in y])
scal_prod=sum([y * x for y, x in zip(y,x)])
```

But if i compute the scalar product first with my code it doesn't:

```
scal_prod=sum([y * x for y, x in zip(y,x)])
y_norm=sum([abs(u) for u in y])
```

According to the message error, with the second version, y is an integer.
And indeed if i return the type of y, it has been changed to integer.

What happened exactly?
Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you run this line:

```
scal_prod=sum([y * x for y, x in zip(y,x)])
```

You iterate the elements in your lists and `y` and `x` are assigned integer values. So `y` no longer refers to your list. Try the following, for example, and you should be fine:

```
scal_prod=sum([a * b for a, b in zip(y,x)])
```

This time, you're using `a` and `b` for your iteration, so `y` still refers to the original list `[1,-2,3]`. Now, because of this, your second line should work.

Comment: Note that this wouldn't have happened if the OP had used a generator expression instead of a list comprehension -- `sum(y * x for y, x in zip(y,x))` -- or had used Python 3.  But it's still a bad idea to reuse variable names like that.

Answer (score 1):

Executing the list comprehension rebinds the label `y`, because you used it as a variable:

```
scal_prod=sum([y * x for y, x in zip(y,x)])
```

After that executes, `y` now refers to the last element of your original list `y`.

Use different variable names to avoid this.